# Is there a way to pass the phone number used for ID Verification through the API?

Tags: docusignapi

When using Docusign's identityVerification option in the api and sending a user to docusign to first verify their identity with a license / passport and then sign a document...

Is there a way to pass the users phone number through to the above page to pre fill the mobile number so that they don't have to enter it in? This is the page where docusign sends and SMS with a link to the mobile number for the user to photograph their license.

[Docusign Mobile Number Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNIuX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jahax, it's just so happens that I published a blog post on this topic today, you can find it here - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-implementing-docusign-recipient-authentication/

However, I'm afraid when it comes to IDV, all the personal information (including phone number) has to be provided directly by the recipient after they click the link sent to them from DocuSign.
If you were using SMS verification (or phone call verification) you could specify the phone number to use yourself, but IDV works differently and at present time - this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quick!